# IOS values passed to a view are lost or forgotten

Tags: objective-c, ios, variables

This is my first app, and actually isn't even fully mine but rather involves re-working an existing app to add functionality.

It involves a JSON feed which I'm successfully reading in and then trying to pass the value of a URL to a view. Here's the code from my app delegate that is successfully fired once the feed is read in:

```
- (void)JSONFetch:(MYJSONFetch *)fetch gotTheCollection:(id)collection 
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    self.testViewController.feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[collection objectForKey:@"Listings"]];

    [JSONFetch release];
    JSONFetch = nil;
}
```

Then in my testViewController I have this viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];


    if(self.feedURL)
    {
        [self startDownload];
    }
}
```

Eventhough, when I debug, the gotTheCollection method passes a value to the feedURL of the view, it then fails on the if(self feedURL) check within the view and thus the view never gets populated.

As I'm so new to this code I've no idea if the sequence is wrong, or maybe it's how I'm passing the variable.

I know the description is relatively vague but even on a basic level I don't know if this functionality works in objective C, it doesn't cause any errors though, just sits there not loading because it can't get the data.

UPDATE: Definition of FeedURL follows, in the H file:

```
NSURL *feedURL;
```

then

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *feedURL;
```

then in the M file:

```
@synthesize feedURL;
```

---

Thanks for the help guys, I finally decided to just restart the entire upgrade as the project had become a mess of reworked code and I couldn't be sure what worked and what didn't. As a result there's no clear answer to this but I imagine Franks was probably the closest so I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: There is couple of things to look at 1) Can testViewController.feedURL retain what it being set on it 2) is the same testViewController instance is brought to the view, so that its viewDidLoad can access what is being set on its feedURL?

Comment: I've updated the question with the definition of feedURL, it's in a H+M file with lots of other declarations so I've only posted the relevant parts. The causes no errors so I have to presume that feedURL is set up ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSURL is being autoreleased, you will need to retain it yourself

Assign the NSURL to feedURL, like so

```
self.testViewController.feedURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:[collection objectForKey:@"Listings"]] retain];
```

This will also mean you will have to release it yourself.